# Boost::Spirit segfault when parsing expressions

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I encounter a segfault when trying to parse expressions with Boost::Spirit.

I simplified the code to just an expression type being either an int either an operation. The parenthesis in the example make the code segfault.

I originally handled the parenthesis but I progressively removed code to get to the simplest example. Isn't the grammar supposed to handle the unknown parenthesis and just fail the parsing?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using std::string;

namespace ast {

struct operation;

using expression = boost::variant<int, boost::recursive_wrapper<operation>>;

struct operation {
  expression lhs_;
  string operator_;
  expression rhs_;
};
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::operation, (ast::expression, lhs_),
                          (string, operator_), (ast::expression, rhs_))

namespace parser {
template <typename Iterator>
struct language_grammar
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type> {
  language_grammar() : language_grammar::base_type(expression) {
    expression = qi::int_ | operation;
    operation = expression >> operator_ >> expression;
    operator_ = "+";
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type> expression;
  qi::rule<Iterator, string()> operator_;
  qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operation(), ascii::space_type> operation;
};
}

int main() {
  string to_parse = "(1 + 2)";
  ast::expression expr;
  parser::language_grammar<string::const_iterator> grammar;
  string::const_iterator iter = to_parse.begin();
  string::const_iterator end = to_parse.end();
  ascii::space_type space;
  bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, space, expr);
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start from `expression` and try to follow what Spirit does. The `int_` fails and so `operation` is tried. Without consuming any input the first element of `operation` (which is `expression`) is tried. The `int_` unsurprisingly fails again and so and endless loop forms.

Comment: I get it. But it also segfaults if I have `expression = [...] | ( "(" >> expression >> ")");` How to explain that one?

Comment: Depends on what `[…]` is. If it's just `int_` I don't think it would segfault(but I'm not an expert). This kind of grammar is "left recursive" and sadly Spirit (being a PEG) does not support it. There are transformations you can make to your grammar to remove that left recursion.

Comment: [...] is the line before. So it gives expression = `qi::int_ | operation | ( "(" >> expression >> ")");` I understand there must be some forbidden recursion somewhere. I guess I need to read more theory. I have the feeling though that the Spirit library should not crash like this. In addition to the template compiler errors this makes the whole pretty obscure to use, especially for a newcomer like me :)

Comment: You need to keep in mind that the alternative parser does not "magically" pick the best option, it tries one by one sequentially until one of them succeeds. So your example never reaches `( "(" >> expression >> ")")`.

Comment: If you put the parentheses alternative before the "naked" `operation` I think any input fully parenthesized would work, but whenever a parenthesis is missing the parser would fail (not crash).